# Voltage Supervisor IC for PIC

Tags: pic, integrated-circuit, battery-operated, brownout

Im using a DS1233A IC with a battery (Li-Ion 4V) powered PIC18F26J50. The battery powers a LM1117 3.3V regulator. The problem i have is when lights go out for long period of times, the battery discharges under the threshold voltage (2.88V).

When the power comes back, it starts loading the battery, but the charging is so slow, that when the voltage is nearing the 2.88V, the reset pin on the IC goes berserk, turning on - off dozens if not hundreds of times until it stabilizes, but every time this happens, the PIC just tilts, and the only way for it to start working is manually reseting it by pulling the battery out and reinserting it, wich is the very issue i want to avoid because its a device located in remote areas and too hard to just go and reset it manually.

Tried the internal brownout reset on the PIC before using the external IC, but it didn't work, i guess because of the same reason the IC doesnt work, and its the extremely slow voltage rise of the battery, wich turns the PIC into a brick.

Is there a solution to a problem like this using what i have?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'tilts'?

Comment: By "tilts" i mean the PIC doesn't run the program, it's like being reset, even after the voltage supervisor stabilized, and the MCLR pin is high level. The only way to make it work again is to turn off the PIC by removing the battery completely and put it back on.

Comment: Tilt = hang or freeze

Comment: Perhaps a reference to actuation of pinball machine tilt sensors?

Comment: You got me there

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your circuit is turning on and loading the source so that it drops below the 2.88V (nominal) threshold, triggering the reset circuit and causing it to restart many times.

One approach which may work if you're not turning on really heavy loads is to use a supply voltage supervisory circuit with some hysteresis. For example, the [TPS3808](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps3808g01.pdf) has 6mV of hysteresis built-in and it can be [increased](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva360/slva360.pdf). There are many such chips available.

If you are turning on really heavy loads you might have to measure the supply voltage with the ADC before making a decision as to whether to power them.

Comment: I see your point, the only loads i have plugged to the battery is the PIC and a SIM900 chip, wich could be the one that's causing the problem... i'll have to find an equivalent IC to the one you posted, i can't get it in the country i'm located. I'll let you know if this solves the problem (i'll probably cut the wires to the SIM900 first and see if the problem persists)